# Shell script that outputs chmod command for all files

Tags: shell-script, echo, variable-substitution

On my EC2 Linux server, I blindly ran chmod 777 at directory that it turns out I should not have. There are hundreds of files in there, and I'm not sure which ones need to go back to their original permissions. I have server with the exact same configurations. So I'm trying to run a shell script that outputs a chmod command for each file in the directory. The plan is that I'd then take the results and execute them in a shell script on the other machine.

I want my output to look like this:

```
sudo chmod ### /somefilepath/
sudo chmod ### /somefilepath/
```

My shell script right now looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in /opt/bitnami/**
do
  perm = "$(stat --format '%a' "$file")"
  echo 'sudo chmod $perm "$file"'
done
```

It errors on each file with perm not found. What am I doing wrong?

I was able to fix this after the response below, final script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

FILES=$(find /opt/bitnami/ -name '*')
for file in $FILES
do
  perm=$(stat --format '%a' "$file")
  echo "sudo chmod $perm $file"
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whitespace is significant:

```
spacing = "matters"  # runs spacing. or tries to, anyways
spacing="matters"    # probably more what you want
```